Where are quantum register operations defined?
Suppose I have three registers of many qubits, $$x, y, r$$
I want to define a quantum gate mapping the sum of $x$ and $y$ to $r$, or more generally from any operation over $x$ and $y$ to $r$. The solution gate must generalize to many qubit input registers. I'm also interested in other arithmetic defined over superposition, such as exclusive or and bit shifting, but only want to give one example for brevity. So I'll stick to the sum $\text{mod } n$. (I know, exclusive or isn't quantum, but just give me some version that is). So after application, the superposition contains some probability for each pair of $x$ and $y$ to a sum in $r$. That is:
$$
|x\rangle = a_x|00\rangle + b_x|10\rangle + c_x|01\rangle + d_x|11\rangle
$$
$$ \text{and} $$
$$
|y\rangle = a_y|00\rangle + b_y|10\rangle + c_y|01\rangle + d_y|11\rangle
$$
And after the sum,
$$
|r\rangle |x\rangle |y\rangle = a_r|000\rangle_r |00\rangle_x |00\rangle_y + b_r|001\rangle_r |01\rangle_x |00\rangle_y + c_r|001\rangle_r |00\rangle_x |01\rangle_y + ... $$
must generalize to many qubit input registers. I'm also interested in other arithmetic defined over superposition, such as exclusive or and bit shifting, but only want to give one example for brevity.
Are these operations already defined somewhere? If so, where?

what do you mean by "exclusive or isn't quantum"?

I read that xor is not invertible in Quantum Computation and Quantum Information. I was asking for an answer that wouldn't give me too much grief about that and hand over an invertible xor.

XOR is invertible, its the CNOT gate

Ok great. Now what about bit shifting?

Bit shifting on its own is clearly not reversible, because the state after the shift clearly destroys some information. You can instead create a gate that looks like $|x\rangle|y\rangle -> |x\rangle |y \oplus (x << 1)\rangle$, i.e. add "x << 1" onto any register. Similar to how the AND gate is not reversible, but mapping the result of an AND to a new register is reversible.

A bitshift of z bits requires that x be added - how do I calculate x from z?

Yes, there are a number of results on this.
There are two main types, one due to Draper, based on QFT.
Any classical boolean circuit can be implemented (with ancilla), leading to another type of adder implemented by porting classical addition algorithms to quantum computers. See this paper from Gidney for example.
Other arithmetic can be done as well, addition can be generalized to multiplication, or via implementing classical multiplication circuits, etc.
Bit shifting on its own is clearly not reversible, because the state after the shift clearly destroys some information. You can instead create a gate that looks like $|x⟩|y⟩\to|x⟩|y⊕(x<<1)⟩$
, i.e. add "$x << 1$" onto any register. Similar to how the AND gate is not reversible, but mapping the result of an AND to a new register is reversible. Here is a white paper that discusses implementation of bit shift

After reading these, I am not left with the impression that the mathematical constraint on the sum over the superposition is computed. That is, QFT or not, the sum is over two specific starting numbers, not the set of all pairs of numbers that have a non-zero probability in superposition.

Also, those are papers, but where sum is defined in, say, qiskit would be nice. It can be any library though.

Lastly, the above two notes goes for the other operation requested.

All of those adders work on superpositions, I'm not sure why you would think that they wouldn't.
The Draper adder is already implemented in qiskit I believe, but all of those can easily be done in any library.
